# Uso del ampersand & en c para guardar valor en las variables

Tags: c

En este código

```
printf("ingrese el numero a guardar");
scanf("%i",&a);
```

¿Cuál es la función del aspersand(&) a la hora de guardar el valor y cual es su nombre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las funciones en `C` *(la mayoría)* inician con minúscula.

La función del `scanf(tipo, &var);` se debe especificar el tipo de dato a leer y la variable. en los tipos puede ser `%i -> Integer , %s-> cadena  , %f  ->  float , %c -> caracter` *(losmáscomunes)*

El otro parámetro que recibe es la variable pero antes aparece el **`& ampersand`** que se usa para **indicar una dirección de memoria de la variable donde se almacenará el dato**

> Teniendo en cuenta que  se omite este `&` cuando se trata de variables
>   de tipo cadena o un `array` de caracteres.

**Por qué se Omite?**

Cuando se declara una variable de tipo `entero , flotante o char` se le asigna una dirección de memoria , como hace `C`  `scanf` para saber en que dirección guardara  el valor ingresado ? mediante el operador `&` *(por referencia)* , para un arreglo o Un String , la variable tendrá también la dirección del primer elemento ya no hace falta pasar el `&` ya que sabrá donde empezará a escribir el valor o `Valores`

Comment: Y que ocurre con los caracteres , obviamente se guardan pero que ocurre por la ausencia del ampersand?

Comment: Cuando dices `Las funciones en C (la mayoría) inician con minúscula.`, te refieres a lowerCamelCase?

Comment: Así es. La mayoría que vi inician en minúscula.

Comment: Tendrías que aclarar que las funciones propias de C inician con minúscula.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente dos aclaraciones:

- el metodo es `printf` y no "Printf".
- el método es `scanf` y no "Scanf".

El valor que introduces en realidad lo estas almacenando en la variable `a`, y en este caso debe ser tipo entero, este es un ejemplo :

```
int a;
printf("ingrese el numero a guardar");
scanf("%i", &a);
printf("El valor del numero a guardar es: %i", a);
```

Utilizando el lenguaje C cuando enviamos valores a una funcion se puede realizar por dos formas:

- Valor
- Referencia

En este caso el ampersand (`&`) significa indicar la dirección en memoria de la variable, enviando el valor por referencia.

Comment: Estoy desde mi teléfono y es difícil escribir bien, quisiera saber porque se usa ese símbolo para guardar variables?

Comment: agregué màs informaciòn a la respuesta.

Comment: Entonces los caracteres se guarda su valor y el resto se guarda por referencia.?