# C, Comparar no me funciona

Tags: c

Quiero comparar en el if, si es numero que haga la funcion principal del programa y si es letra que imprima una frase pero no funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char seguir, a;
float gg, tot, n1, n2;

printf("\t\t\tCuanto cuesta.");
printf("\nEste programa te dice cuanto cuesta cada item de un paquete,");
printf("\npor ejemplo, cuanto cuesta cada galleta de un paquete que cuesta n");
printf("\n==============================================================================");

do{
printf("\n\nCuanto costo el paquete / bolsa / etc: ");
scanf("%f", n1);

if ((n1>=48)&&(n1<=57)){
printf("\nCuantos items hay?: ");
scanf("%f", &n2);

tot=n1/n2;
printf("\nEl valor de cada item es: %.5f centavos", tot);
}
else{
    printf("Escribe un numero por favor");
}

printf("\n\nQuieres hacerlo de nuevo?: (s/n) ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c", &seguir);
system("cls");

}while(seguir != 'n');

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber en que dirección guardara el valor ingresado `scanf` , lo hace mediante el operador `&` *(por referencia)* qué es lo que hace falta en su ejercicio. [Pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59793/uso-del-ampersand-en-c-para-guardar-valor-en-las-variables/59799#59799)

```
scanf("%f", n1);
```

Además de esto tiene el mismo error que en una [pregunta formulada anteriormente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108009/c%C3%B3mo-imprimir-una-frase-al-azar/108016#108016) , En la parte de las opciones `S/N scanf("%c", &seguir);` no espera si no que salta esto es debido a la tecla `ENTER` *(salto de linea , aún está en el buffer)* para solucionar bastaría con añadir un espacio al inicio.

**Código final** *(Modifiqué el mensaje del else)*  <kbd>[Ver Demo Online](https://repl.it/M5IL)</kbd>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char seguir, a;
float gg, tot, n1, n2;

printf("\t\t\tCuanto cuesta.");
printf("\nEste programa te dice cuanto cuesta cada item de un paquete,");
printf("\npor ejemplo, cuanto cuesta cada galleta de un paquete que cuesta n");
printf("\n==============================================================================");

do{
printf("\n\nCuanto costo el paquete / bolsa / etc: ");
scanf("%f", &n1);

if ((n1>=48)&&(n1<=57)){
printf("\nCuantos items hay?: ");
scanf(" %f", &n2);

tot=n1/n2;
printf("\nEl valor de cada item es: %.5f centavos", tot);
}
else{
    printf("Escribe un numero entre el rango 48-57");
}

printf("\n\nQuieres hacerlo de nuevo?: (s/n) ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf(" %c", &seguir);
//system("cls");

}while(seguir != 'n');

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Esta mal, lo acabo de compilar

Comment: @Jenio158 Qué está mal ? ¿Donde lo compiló? revisar nuevamente por favor y comentar el resultado.

Comment: Uso codeblocks para programar. Lo compilo y si pongo un numero, me tira la linea de else, que no deberia

Comment: @Jenio158 lo que se está comparando son `floats` es normal que muestre el mensaje del `else` así sea un número, si el número no está en un rango especificado mostrará el mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema que estás teniendo, que no te permite tomar el valor de n1 es que te olvidaste de poner "&" antes de la variable. Por lo tanto la función Scanf no sabe en qué dirección de memoria se encuentra la variable n1.

Deberías cambiar la línea:

```
scanf("%f", n1);
```

por la siguiente:

```
scanf("%f", &n1);
```

Obviando las cuestiones lógicas del programa de esa forma sí obtendrías los datos para hacer los cálculos que escribiste.

Más info sobre Scanf en la [web cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Respondiendo a tu comentario. Si lo que querés es hacer un simple cálculo. Creo que deberías multiplicar en vez de dividir además de que el if no tendría mucho sentido. El código lo imagino de esta forma:

```
do{
    printf("\n\nCuanto costo el paquete / bolsa / etc: ");
    scanf("%f", &n1);

    printf("\nCuantos items hay?: ");
    scanf("%f", &n2);

    tot= n1*n2;
    printf("\nEl valor de cada item es: %.2f centavos", tot);

    printf("\n\nQuieres hacerlo de nuevo?: (s/n) ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &seguir);
    system("cls");

}while(seguir != 'n');
```

Comment: Esque ese & lo borre porque cuando ponia un numero me tiraba la linea: printf("Escribe un numero por favor");       y no deberia, deberia de entrar en el if no en el else

Comment: Ahí edité mi respuesta para ver si te sirve.

Comment: Para que eliminas los if? lo que quiero hacer es proteger al programa, asi estaba cuando inicie.

Comment: Al dar falsa la condición "((n1>=48)&&(n1<=57))" Veías por consola sólo "Escribe un numero por favor". Así, como lo que yo te pegué, se puede calcular el precio del producto por la cantidad comprada.

Comment: Osea el programa sirve. Pero yo queria agregar una condicion por si alguien elegia una letra

Answer (score 0):

> Quiero comparar en el if, si es numero que haga la funcion principal del programa y si es letra que imprima una frase pero no funciona:

`scanf` devuelve un entero que indica cuántos elementos ha podido leer satisfactoriamente.

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar ese valor de retorno para saber si se ha introducido un número:

```
if( scanf("%f", &n1) == 1 )
```

Pero claro, si la lectura no ha sido correcta entonces se habrá quedado basura en el buffer de entrada. Lamentablemente `fflush` **no debería** usarse para limpiar el buffer de entrada ya que esta función está pensada para trabajar con buffers de salida. Así mismo no hay una función propia para limpiar el buffer de entrada... lo más común es hacer esto:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Aplicando esto tu código debería quedar así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

  char seguir, a;
  float gg, tot, n1, n2;

  printf("\t\t\tCuanto cuesta.");
  printf("\nEste programa te dice cuanto cuesta cada item de un paquete,");
  printf("\npor ejemplo, cuanto cuesta cada galleta de un paquete que cuesta n");
  printf("\n=============================================================================");

  do{
    printf("\n\nCuanto costo el paquete / bolsa / etc: ");
    if( scanf("%f", &n1) == 1 )
    {
      printf("\nCuantos items hay?: ");
      scanf("%f", &n2);

      tot=n1/n2;
      printf("\nEl valor de cada item es: %.5f centavos", tot);
    }
    else{
      printf("\nEscribe un numero por favor");
    }

    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }

    printf("\n\nQuieres hacerlo de nuevo?: (s/n) ");

    scanf("%c", &seguir);

  }while(seguir != 'n');

  return 0;

}
```